# SlideToggle animation breaks with image and text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a slidetoggle to work properly on a div.  I have html in the following format:

```
<div class="root-div first-service">
     <div class="title-div gradient">
          <div class="title-div-left">
               <p>$ServiceName</p>
          </div>
          <div class="title-div-right">
               <p>&#x25B2;</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="description-div show minimum-height">
           <div class="description-content-div">
                $ServiceDescription
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services-image-two">
           <img src="themes/theinneryou/images/ServicesImage2.jpg" alt="Missing Image"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

I also have javascript as follows:

```
$('.title-div').on('click', function () {
    var arrow = $(this).find('.title-div-right');
    if (proceed) {
        proceed = false;
        $(this).closest('.root-div').find('.services-image-two').slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).closest('.root-div')
        .find('.description-div')
            .slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $(arrow).text().trim().charCodeAt(0) == 9650 ? $(arrow).html('<p>&#x25BC;</p>') : $(arrow).html('<p>&#x25B2;</p>');
                proceed = true;
            });
    }
});
```

The effect that I get is that the image itself plays the animation of slide and then gets hidden, then the rest of the next div which contains text only gets hidden without any animation.  The image is overlapping the text div as I have it under absolute positioning.  You can see the live demo at tiu.azularis.com/Services

Is there a way to make them gracefuly slide together when I click the arrow and then appear together when I click the down arrow?

I also tried moving the image div inside the description div and also tried setting .delay after first animation, but neither does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line 83 in Services.css:

```
.services-wrapper .expansion-wrap .first-service .minimum-height {
    /* min-height: 20.4rem; */
    height: 20.4rem;
}
```

`min-height` is messing it up.

Otherwise you have to fix your HTML + CSS for that whole section because it is not ideal.

Comment: That content is going to wary in height, if I continue using min-height, any other way around this problem?

Comment: I would look into something like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for a responsive grid system that even has your collapse elements. Otherwise you could dynamically set the height of the div based on the image height with a little Javascript.

Comment: Sure you can [join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69633/tomanow)